# Hosts name gives DNS server error when trying to connect to the application

Tags: iis, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I am trying to connect to IIS Server, from the browser within the company network (application can only access from intranet) but I am unable to connect. I want to validate below scenario that is the root course or not for this connection issue.

When I try to connect to application from browser, I get DNS Error.

```
DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist)
Please check that the host name has been spelled correctly.
```

I have 2 different servers. I need to move a current running application that hosted in one server `(Server A)` and move it another server `(Server B)`.

These 2 servers have SSL certificates. But both has same issue to value.
For a example `Server A` has issue to value as `myappname.companyname.com`
For `Server B` has issue to value as `myappname.companyname.com.`

In the `Server A` hosts file’s server ip is map to below value. It is same as `issue to` value in SSL certificate.
In example
`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx myappname.companyname.com`

When I am setting up server B, I mapped the ip address as below

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx myappname-test.companyname.com`

Now I am trying to ping the servers using host name but I can only ping to `myappname.companyname.com`.

When I try to ping `myappname-test.companyname.com` host address it gives me this message.

```
Ping request could not find host myappname-test.companyname.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

I checked all other settings in both servers and seems all are same and no other conflicts. I am wondering is this the issue for this DNS related issue.

Comment: Check your DNS server settings by using `ipconfig /all`, check your hosts file (located in X:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc). It should be reseted if it contains some non-default records. Check your firewall (bundled or external if you have any) settings. It might block ping utility or everything except your browser. Check your antivirus software if you have it to block some network/software.